# Update cannot find MSA60-cabinet

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-storageworks, hpe

We have a MSA60 connected to a P812-controller in a DL360 G6-server, and I've been trying to update the MSA60 to version 2.28 for about 2 weeks now using different methods but to no avail.

What has been tested so far:

- Offline update via HP SUM from Service Pack for ProLiant 2017.04
- Offline update via HP SUM from Smart Update Firmware DVD 10.10
- Offline update via HP SUM from Smart Update Firmware DVD 9.30

The following versions are installed:

- DL360: CentOS 7
- P410i-controller: 6.64
- P812-controller: 6.64
- MSA60: 2.18

What is happening is that I boot with a medium, open a terminal and try to install the update

```
$ cd /mnt/boot/hp/swpackages
$ ./CP013530.scexe -q
```

And I get the following output:

*Service Pack for ProLiant 2017.04*

```
HP Enclosure ROM 2.28 Flash

No devices updated
```

*Smart Update Firmware DVD 10.10*

```
HP Enclosure ROM 2.28 Flash
    Smart Array controller in slot 0 - something about no update needed

No devices updated
```

*Smart Update Firmware DVD 9.30*

```
HP Enclosure ROM 2.28 Flash
    Smart Array controller in slot 0 - something about no update needed

    Smart Array controller in slot 3 - something about no update needed

No devices updated
```

Slot 0 is the P410i and slot 3 is the P812

Other things I've tried

- Downgrading the P812 to 5.56
- Disabling the P410i in BIOS
- Disconnecting all drives from the MSA60
- HP SUM graphical update (9.30, 10.10 and 2017.04)
- 4 different updates (from disks and downloaded from hp)
- Switched port of MSA60 in P812 from 4 to other ones
- Changed SAS-cable
- Restarted chassis several times

The installation mediums are made with the HP USB Key Utility into a USB-stick.

The backplanes and midplane of the MSA60 are "new" enough as mentioned in https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c01361896

I have sniffed around the HPE-forum which didn't help me enough, and I am now running out of ideas. Any advices?

Comment: Why all the downvoting though? What can I improve about this question?

Answer (score 2):

This equipment is just too old.

The MSA60 was a 2007-era product and was end-of-life by 2010/2011. I definitely wouldn't recommend running anything critical on it.

Is there a reason you need version 2.28? It was released in 2011, but the changelog doesn't show much of an improvement over your current version.

Comment: The intended use of the enclosure is simple backup offshore storage (one of many), so it is nothing critical there. I saw that there was an update for it so I was more or less thinking "why not" regarding updating it.